# How to obtain user roles from Azure Active Directory using ADAL

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, adal

I am working on an Android application which uses the [ADAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-android) library to authenticate users, now there's a requirement that certain actions should be shown for a specific group of users based on their AD roles. How do I access the roles for AD users?
The Android app interacts with an ASP.NET Web API service

Answer (score 0):

If by roles you mean group memberships, there are at least 2 ways:

1. Set groupMembershipClaims to "SecurityGroup" or "All" in your app's manifest in AAD

   - This makes it so you receive the users' group memberships in the id token (which gives you the user's name etc.)
   - What is returned are only ids of groups, not names
   - There is a limit of max 200 group ids returned
   - You can find some info [here](http://www.dushyantgill.com/blog/2014/12/10/authorization-cloud-applications-using-ad-groups/), though it is for the old portal (manifest management is easier in new portal)
2. Or you can get group memberships from Microsoft Graph API: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_getmembergroups

   - You will need to get an access token for MS Graph API in your app to be able to call it
   - If you expect your users to possibly be members of a 200 groups or more, this is the only option you have